# Auto Click With Type or Value Tag

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have a website for which I would like to create a JavaScript bookmarklet for autoclicking, but the site does not use an ID tag. Here is the code of site:

```
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Find Product" 
onclick="return incrementClicksTest('2','true')" class="buttonSubmit">
```

I used this JavaScript bookmarklet:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('any_id_here').click()
```

It works fine for buttons with IDs, but how do I go about making a bookmarklet using the name, value, and type tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].click();
```

**Sample Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/dcRsc/

Now, that will work if your button  is the first input in your page.

Use this if you have numerous elements in your page:

```
var elems =document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
{
    if(elems[i].type=="submit" && elems[i].name =="Submit")
    {
        elems[i].click();        
        break;
    }
}
```

**Sample Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/dcRsc/1/

That will trigger the `click` event of your submit button, with Submit name.

Furthermore (and since your button already has a css class) you could use the `getElementsByClassName()` method:

```
var elems =document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSubmit");

for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
{
    if(elems[i].name =="Submit")
    {
        elems[i].click();        
        break;
    }
}
```

**Sample Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/dcRsc/2/

That will get all elements with the `buttonSubmit` class applied.

Or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("buttonSubmit")[0].click();
```

If your button is the only element in the page with that class on it, hence avoiding the `for` loop altogether.